# ActionController::UnknownFormat in DocumentHistoriesController# with a format.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to call a partial on a form and have the partial update without refreshing the rest of the form.

The partial is called in my complaints form

```
 <div id="refresh_assigned">
    <%= render :partial => '/document_histories/history_for_complaint_form' %>
 </div>
```

I am calling a delete in \document_histories_history_for_complaint_form.html.erb

```
    <td><%= link_to 'Delete', history, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure that you want to remove this users assignment to this complaint? \n \n The user will NOT be notified via email. "} %></td>
```

My destroy def in the document_histories controller is

```
 def destroy
    @document_history.destroy
    respond_to do |format|

      format.js {}
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @document_history }

    end
  end
```

I have a js file of \app\views\document_histories\destroy.js.erb

```
$('#refresh_assigned').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'document_histories/history_for_complaint_form')).html_safe %>");
```

The error I am getting is

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat in DocumentHistoriesController#destroy
ActionController::UnknownFormat
Rails.root: C:/Users/cmendla/RubymineProjects/internal_complaints
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/document_histories_controller.rb:209:in `destroy'
```

Line 209 is respond_to do |format|

---

Here is the log when I try to delete after making the change suggested by Pavan. It looks like I am getting a Nil class error when trying to refresh the div

```
Started DELETE "/document_histories/364" for ::1 at 2016-02-23 09:22:21 -0500
Processing by DocumentHistoriesController#destroy as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"364"}
  [1m[35mUser Load (1.0ms)[0m  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  [1m[36mDocumentHistory Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "document_histories".* FROM "document_histories" WHERE "document_histories"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 364]]
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  begin transaction
  [1m[36mSQL (9.0ms)[0m  [1mDELETE FROM "document_histories" WHERE "document_histories"."id" = ?[0m  [["id", 364]]
  [1m[35m (11.0ms)[0m  commit transaction
  Rendered document_histories/_history_for_complaint_form.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered document_histories/destroy.js.erb (5.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 42ms (ActiveRecord: 21.0ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):
     8:       <th> Remarks</th>
     9:     </tr>
    10: 
    11:   <% @document_histories.each do |history| %>
    12: 
    13: 
    14: 
  app/views/document_histories/_history_for_complaint_form.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_document_histories__history_for_complaint_form_html_erb___652294712_44088072'
  app/views/document_histories/destroy.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_document_histories_destroy_js_erb___293771988_76518024'


  Rendered C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.text.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.text.erb (19.0ms)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ActionController::UnknownFormat in DocumentHistoriesController#destroy

You need to add `remote: true` to your link to send `JS` request to the controller.

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', history, remote: true, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure that you want to remove this users assignment to this complaint? \n \n The user will NOT be notified via email. "} %>
```

Now the request is handled with `format.js` in the controller action.

Comment: I  added the remote:true . I am not getting the error but the div is not refreshing.

Comment: @ChrisMendla What is the log look like after my changes?

Comment: I got it working. I had to define the the @document_histories by adding the following line to the destroy def ` @document_histories = DocumentHistory.where(["complaint_id like ?", "%#{$current_record_id}%"])`